# Varna of Nandagopa and Maa Yashoda?

Tags: krishna, caste-system, varna, shudra, vaishya

Gopala bhatta goswami in his sat kriya sandarba mentions the 11 jatis of shudra varna (pic below)

While Swami karpatri had said that they're Vaishyas (like other gowala-s)

So were Nandagopa, Maa Yashoda and the gopa gopikas sat shudras or Vaishyas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: As per [this book](https://books.google.co.in/books?redir_esc=y&id=wT-BAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22Nanda%2C+who+was+also+a+king%22), Nanda baba was Kshatriya..by profession (husbandry) u can consider them Vaishyas..

Answer (score 0):

As per **brahmavaivartapurANa-brahmakhanDa-ch10**, gopas are mentioned as sat-shudras alongwith other sat-shudras like barbers, modaka sellers, weavers, traders, etc. :

[image]